# Blazor Server app on Azure App Services returns: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(byte[] plaintext)

Tags: logging, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

A previously fine running Blazor Server (.Net 6) application stops running on Azure App Services.
In that application a custom logging provider is used to log information into a database.  This has been running for a year without any problems.  Recently it gives an Internal Server Error: CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(byte[] plaintext)

When running the application in Debug mode in VS2022 it behaves correctly and logging is working fine.

When removing the custom Database logger extension, the application also runs fine again.

Comment: Is the data encrypting happening inside the custom logging provider? Is the same `plaintext` being passed?

Comment: @RyanHill Thx for replying. No encryption is done in the custom logging provider. I can share the full stack dump, is there a possibility to add an attachment?

Comment: You can't on here, but you can add an attachment on a [Q&A question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask/) or send it to me via email to AzCommunity[at]microsoft[dot]com. Make sure you use _ATTN: Ryan_ in the subject line and with a link to this post.

Comment: @RyanHill thx for your time.  In the mean while I have pinpointed the problem.  It had nothing to do with DataProtection or alike... In my DbLogger.cs class I made an error on handling the formatter argument of the call 
    Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
Setting this correct solved the problem. (Why it worked for several months and suddenly it didn't anymore... who nows?)

Comment: Best guess I have is there was a fix applied to the underlying runtime. Have to check the dotnet repo releases to see if there were any changes.